# second largest absolute value form array in php

Tags: php, arrays, absolute

second largest absolute value form array

> input : array(13, -12, 8, 2, 5)
>
> expected answer : 12

here is my code

```
<?php
function print2largest($arr, $arr_size)
{
    if ($arr_size < 2)
    {
        echo(" Invalid Input ");
        return;
    }     
    $first = $second = PHP_INT_MIN;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $arr_size ; $i++)
    {
        if ($arr[$i] > $first)
        {
            $second = $first;
            $first = $arr[$i];
        }

        else if ($arr[$i] > $second &&
                 $arr[$i] != $first)
            $second = $arr[$i];
    }
    if ($second == PHP_INT_MIN)
        echo("There is no second largest element\n");
    else
        echo("The second largest element is " . $second . "\n");
}     
$arr = array(13, -12, 8, 2, 5);
$n = sizeof($arr);
print2largest($arr, $n);
?>
```

> output i got : 8

Comment: if the number is less than zero, multiply it by `-1`.  So, if `$arr[$i] < 0`; then `$arr[$i] *= -1`

Comment: why `-12`? `8>-12`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It can be easy done in "php-way":

```
$arr = array(13, -12, 8, 2, 5);
$absoluteArr = array_map('abs', array_unique($arr));
rsort($absoluteArr);
echo $absoluteArr[1];
```

Comment: Very elegant. I like it

Answer (score 2):

No need to do that much code, do directly:

```
<?php

    $array  = array(13, -12, 8, 2, 5);
    $final_array = array_unique(array_map('abs',$array)); // remove duplicates and apply abs() to all elements
    rsort($final_array,SORT_NUMERIC); //reverse sort array numerically

    echo $final_array[1]; //get second highest
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/mgjaO

Reference:-

[abs()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php)

[array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

[array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

[rsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this needs a function, if you just [rsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) the array after each element has been updated with the [absolute](http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php) value with [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)and look at the second position:

```
function print2largest($arr) {
    if (count($arr) < 2) {
        echo(" Invalid Input ");
        return;
    }

    $arr = array_map("abs", $arr);
    rsort($arr);
    return $arr[1];
}

$arr = array(13, -11, 9, 2, 5);
print2largest($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add abs() to the values here

```
function print2largest($arr, $arr_size)
{
if ($arr_size < 2)
{
    echo(" Invalid Input ");
    return;
}

$first = $second = PHP_INT_MIN;
for ($i = 0; $i < $arr_size ; $i++)
{
    if (abs($arr[$i]) > $first)
    {
        $second = $first;
        $first = abs($arr[$i]);
    }

    else if (abs($arr[$i]) > $second &&
             abs($arr[$i]) != $first)
        $second = abs($arr[$i]);
}
if ($second == PHP_INT_MIN)
    echo("There is no second largest elementn");
else
    echo("The second largest element is " . $second . "n");
}

$arr = array(13, -12, 8, 2, 5);
$n = sizeof($arr);
print2largest($arr, $n);
```

> > The second largest element is 12n

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [13, -12, 8, 2, 5];
echo getSecondLargestAbsolute($array); // 12

function getSecondLargestAbsolute($array)
{
    $values = [];
    if (count($array) == count($array, COUNT_RECURSIVE)) {
        $values = $array;
    } else {
        foreach (new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveArrayIterator($array)) as $item) {
            $values[] = $item;
        };
    }

    array_walk($values, function (&$val){
        return $val = abs($val);
    });

    rsort($values);

    return $values[1];
}
```